# How to pull back an email that has already been sent?

Tags: windows, security, html-email, email-attachments, aol

Somehow, I sent a sensitive email with an attachment to the wrong email address. Is there a way to invalidate (or pull back) this email and the attachment remotely? The email was sent out via aol.com email agent.

I know there is a way to invalidate an attachment sent along with the email, but not sure about the email itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no a way to unsend an email, gmail is not facebook.